# Calculating conditional propotions using mutate

Tags: r, tidyverse, dplyr

I am working with a data set like this.

```r
library(magrittr)
library(tidyverse)

time<- c("day1", "day1", "day1", "day2", "day2", "day2", "day3", "day3", "day3")
indviduals<- c(23,25,26,22,24,20,21,23,15)
treatment<- c(rep(c("a", "b", "c")))
dat<-NULL

dat <- dat %>% cbind(treatment, time, indviduals)%>%
  as.data.frame(stringAsFactors=F)
str(dat)
```

I want to know how to calculate the percentage of individuals alive by day and by treatment. In othe words I want a fourth column that give
give me the a proportion of individual "alive". I want to take the indivuduals in day 1 minus those of day2 divide them by 100
and do this for every day and treatment.

#### What I want is something that looks like this:

```
  dat$prop<- c(1, 1,1,.99,.99,.94, .98, .98, .89)
```

woudl really appreciate some insight!
thanks!

I have try using gather and then mutate but I am unsure of what to put as argument inside mutate()

```
>   dat <- dat %>%
>     gather(time, individuals, -treatment) %>%
>     group_by(treatment, day) %>%
>     mutate("prop" = 1 - ((#first value of ind day 1 - #value of ind day 2) / 100 by treatment))
```

Comment: You created `dat` with all `factor` columns instead it can be `dat <- data.frame(treatment, time, indviduals, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`, `cbind` converts to matrix and matrix can hold only a single class

Comment: Do you need `dat %>% group_by(treatment) %>% mutate(prop = round(1 - (first(indviduals)/indviduals[2])/100, 2))`

Comment: @akrun No I don't really need to do it like that but I was trying stuff to see what could work and mutate seemed like the right option

Comment: You meant, you want to do `gather`, Not sure and also pleasee checek the `str(dat)` created if you think that `as.data.frame(cbind` is the better way

Comment: I think I fixed data now. I don't necessary want to use gather, I am open to other ways to solve this.

Comment: I meant, whether the `dat %>% group_by(treatment) %>% mutate(prop = round(1 - (first(indviduals)/indviduals[2])/100, 2))` logic is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `dplyr`, we can `group_by` `treatment` and calculate `prop` by subtracting `first` value in  `indviduals` by `indviduals` divided by 100.

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>% 
  group_by(treatment) %>% 
  mutate(prop = 1 - (first(indviduals) - indviduals)/100)


#  time  indviduals treatment  prop
#  <chr>      <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>
#1 day1          23 a          1   
#2 day1          25 b          1   
#3 day1          26 c          1   
#4 day2          22 a          0.99
#5 day2          24 b          0.99
#6 day2          20 c          0.94
#7 day3          21 a          0.98
#8 day3          23 b          0.98
#9 day3          15 c          0.89
```

This can also be done in base R using `ave`

```
dat$prop <- with(dat, 1 - (ave(indviduals, treatment, 
                 FUN = function(x) x[1]) - indviduals)/100)
```

Or using `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[, prop := 1 - (first(indviduals) - indviduals)/100, treatment]
```

**data**

```
dat <- data.frame(time, indviduals, treatment, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```